# Perl - reading a file line by line in reverse order

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read lines from the end of file in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303053/how-can-i-read-lines-from-the-end-of-file-in-perl)

First read the last line, and then the last but one, etc. The file is too big to fit into memory.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303053/how-can-i-read-lines-from-the-end-of-file-in-perl.

Comment: Sounds like you're implementing the unix trace command in perl, or similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading lines in reverse order:

```
use File::ReadBackwards;

my $back = File::ReadBackwards->new(shift @ARGV) or die $!;
print while defined( $_ = $back->readline );
```

I misread the question initially and thought you wanted to **read backward and forward, in alternating fashion** -- which seems more interesting. :)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::ReadBackwards ;

sub read_forward_and_backward {
    # Takes a file name and a true/false value.
    # If true, the first line returned will be from end of file.
    my ($file_name, $read_from_tail) = @_;

    # Get our file handles.
    my $back = File::ReadBackwards->new($file_name) or die $!;
    open my $forw, '<', $file_name or die $!;

    # Return an iterator.
    my $line;    
    return sub {
        return if $back->tell <= tell($forw);
        $line = $read_from_tail ? $back->readline : <$forw>;
        $read_from_tail = not $read_from_tail;
        return $line;
    }

}

# Usage.    
my $iter = read_forward_and_backward(@ARGV);
print while defined( $_ = $iter->() );
```

Comment: It is important to note that File::ReadBackwards is not a core module. See: https://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-F.html

Answer (score 8):

Simple if [`tac`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tac_(Unix)) is available:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
no warnings 'exec';
use strict;

open my $fh, "-|", "tac", @ARGV
  or die "$0: spawn tac failed: $!";

print while <$fh>;
```

Run on itself:

```
$ ./readrev readrev
print while <$fh>;

  or die "$0: spawn tac failed: $!";
open my $fh, "-|", "tac", @ARGV

use strict;
no warnings 'exec';
use warnings;

#! /usr/bin/perl
```

Comment: Do you know how to use this solution when the file is utf8 encoded?

Comment: Figured it out myself - in case others need to know: ... use Encode; ... binmode STDOUT, ':utf8'; ... print decode_utf8 ($_) ...

Answer (score 3):

I've used [`PerlIO::reverse`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlIO::reverse) for doing this recently. I prefer the IO layer of `PerlIO::reverse` over the custom object or tied handle interface offered by `File::ReadBackwards`.