# extract last 10 minutes from logfile

Tags: bash, date, datetime, logfiles

Trying to find a simple way for watching for recent events (from less than 10 minutes), I've tried this:

```
awk "/^$(date --date="-10 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M")/{p++} p" /root/test.txt
```

but it doesn't work as expected...

Log files are in form :

```
Dec 18 09:48:54 Blah
Dec 18 09:54:47 blah bla
Dec 18 09:55:33 sds
Dec 18 09:55:38 sds
Dec 18 09:57:58 sa
Dec 18 09:58:10 And so on...
```

Comment: Do you want log messages from the last 10 minutes of actual time or the last 10 minutes relative to the end of the log?

Comment: This type of stuff gets messy in plain shell -- especially since the date command you have to use for the solution varies from system to system. Can I give you an answer in Perl? If not, I'll give you one that works for BSD (I have a Mac), and you'll have to figure it out for Linux (if that's what you have).

Comment: @DavidW. bash do offer now a lot of powerfull tips for doing this kind of tricks... (See my answer). Anyway perl stay my first choice for this kind of jobs.

Comment: @tripleee This is not a real duplicate, as the goal there is to read bunch of time upto end of file. Other question stand for interval of time inside one log file.

Comment: @FHauri Not having an end condition is just a simpler case of the same problem, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can match the date range using simple string comparison, for example:

```
d1=$(date --date="-10 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M")
d2=$(date "+%b %_d %H:%M")
while read line; do
    [[ $line > $d1 && $line < $d2 || $line =~ $d2 ]] && echo $line
done
```

For example if `d1='Dec 18 10:19'` and `d2='Dec 18 10:27'` then the output will be:

```
Dec 18 10:19:16
Dec 18 10:19:23
Dec 18 10:21:03
Dec 18 10:22:54
Dec 18 10:27:32
```

Or using `awk` if you wish:

```
awk -v d1="$d1" -v d2="$d2" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2'
```

Comment: What if there are some different months in the timestamps?  I think the string comparisons can break down.  e.g. `[[ "Jan 18 10:27:32" < "Feb 18 10:27:32" ]] && echo "older"` and `[[ "Feb 18 10:27:32" < "Mar 18 10:27:32" ]] && echo "older"` give inconsistent results.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma True, if the time period covers a change of month, my solution won't work. Your solution is more accurate, and you have my upvote.

Comment: @janos New bash version offer a builtin `date` function by using `printf "%(...)T" -1`. This is a lot quicker than using a *fork* to `date`. For using *endianess* property of date, you could correct month entry by using *associative array*. See my answer!

Answer (score 13):

Here is nice tool
range is any you wish from -10 till now

```
sed -n "/^$(date --date='10 minutes ago' '+%b %_d %H:%M')/,\$p" /var/log/blaaaa
```

Comment: its cool. Superfast even when the logs is huge. what if i want xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [25/Oct/2014:22:42:45 +0800] "GET, how to edit the sed command? I tried date --date='1 minutes ago' '+[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M' but it didn't work

Comment: My log lines start with `2017-06-28 14:00` so I modified the sed command as follows: `sed -n "/^$(date --date="60 minutes ago" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")/,\$p" /var/log/blah.log` to get the last 60 minutes of the log

Comment: [tag:sed] is superfast, but string comparisons can break down if months differ in timelapse!! This approach is **fragile**.

Answer (score 9):

### Introduction

This answer is something long, because there is 3 different way on thinking: **1)** [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) quick or exact, **2)** pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and **3)** [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function.

### That's a (common) job for [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)!:

Simple and efficient:

```
perl -MDate::Parse -ne 'print if/^(.{15})\s/&&str2time($1)>time-600' /path/log
```

This version print last 10 minutes event, upto ***now***, by using `time` function.

You could test this with:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog |
  perl -MDate::Parse -ne '
    print if /^(\S+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)\s/ && str2time($1) > time-600'
```

Note that first representation use only *firsts 15 chars from each lines*, while second construct use more detailed *regexp*.

As a perl script: `last10m.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wn

use strict;
use Date::Parse;
print if /^(\S+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)\s/ && str2time($1) > time-600
```

#### Strictly: *extract last 10 minutes from logfile*

Meaning not relative to current time, but to last entry in logfile:

There is two way for retrieving *end of period*:

```
date -r logfile +%s
tail -n1 logfile | perl -MDate::Parse -nE 'say str2time($1) if /^(.{15})/'
```

Where logically, last modification time of the logfile must be the time of the last entry.

So the command could become:

```
perl -MDate::Parse -ne 'print if/^(.{15})\s/&&str2time($1)>'$(
    date -r logfile +%s)
```

or you could take **the** last entry as reference:

```
perl -MDate::Parse -E 'open IN,"<".$ARGV[0];seek IN,-200,2;while (<IN>) {
    $ref=str2time($1) if /^(\S+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)/;};seek IN,0,0;
    while (<IN>) {print if /^(.{15})\s/&&str2time($1)>$ref-600}' logfile
```

Second version seem stronger, but access to file only once.

As a perl script, this could look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Date::Parse;
my $ref;                 # The only variable I will use in this.

open IN,"<".$ARGV[0];    # Open (READ) file submited as 1st argument
seek IN,-200,2;          # Jump to 200 character before end of logfile. (This
                         # could not suffice if log file hold very log lines! )
while (<IN>) {           # Until end of logfile...
    $ref=str2time($1) if /^(\S+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)/;
};                       # store time into $ref variable.
seek IN,0,0;             # Jump back to the begin of file
while (<IN>) {
    print if /^(.{15})\s/&&str2time($1)>$ref-600;
}
```

### But if you really wanna use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

There is a very quick **pure bash** script:

**Warning**: This use recent *bashisms*, require `$BASH_VERSION` 4.2 or higher.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A month

for i in {1..12};do
    LANG=C printf -v var "%(%b)T" $(((i-1)*31*86400))
    month[$var]=$i
  done

printf -v now "%(%s)T" -1
printf -v ref "%(%m%d%H%M%S)T" $((now-600))

while read line;do
    printf -v crt "%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d" ${month[${line:0:3}]} \
        $((10#${line:4:2})) $((10#${line:7:2})) $((10#${line:10:2})) \
        $((10#${line:13:2}))
    # echo " $crt < $ref ??"   # Uncomment this line to print each test
    [ $crt -gt $ref ] && break
done
cat
```

Store this script and run:

```
cat >last10min.sh
chmod +x last10min.sh
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | ./last10min.sh
```

#### Strictly: *extract last 10 minutes from logfile*

Simply replace line 10, but you have to place filename **in** the script and not use it as a filter:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A month

for i in {1..12};do
    LANG=C printf -v var "%(%b)T" $(((i-1)*31*86400))
    month[$var]=$i
  done

read now < <(date -d "$(tail -n1 $1|head -c 15)" +%s)
printf -v ref "%(%m%d%H%M%S)T" $((now-600))

export -A month

{
    while read line;do
        printf -v crt "%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d" ${month[${line:0:3}]} \
            $((10#${line:4:2})) $((10#${line:7:2})) $((10#${line:10:2})) \
            $((10#${line:13:2}))
        [ $crt -gt $ref ] && break
    done
    cat
} <$1
```

## A [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script into a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function

As [commented by *`ajcg`*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/111226080?noredirect=1), this could be nice to put efficient perl script into a bash function:

```
recentLog(){ 
    perl -MDate::Parse -ne '
        print if/^(.{'${3:-15}'})\s/ &&
            str2time($1)>time-'$((
                60*${2:-10}
            )) ${1:-/var/log/daemon.log}
}
```

Usage:

`recentLog [filename] [minutes] [time sting length]`

- `filename` of log file
- `minutes` max before now of lines to show
- `time sting length` from begin of lines (default `15`).

Comment: This use *[big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)* property of date, but correct text rendered month by using a *bash associative array*.

Comment: `./last10min.sh: line 6: printf: `(': invalid format character
./last10min.sh: line 7: month[$var]: bad array subscript
./last10min.sh: line 9: printf: `(': invalid format character
./last10min.sh: line 10: printf: `(': invalid format character
./last10min.sh: line 17: [: 1809485400: unary operator expected
./last10min.sh: line 17: [: 1809544700: unary operator expected
./last10min.sh: line 17: [: 1809553300: unary operator expected`

Comment: it doesnt work.. any idea?

Comment: as for perl method: syntax error at ./test.py line 3, near "-ne"
Execution of ./test.py aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: I have installed perl-TimeDate to clear the error. runing cat /root/scripts/logs_scripts/test.txt | perl -MDate::Parse -ne 'print if /^(\S+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)\s/ && str2time($1) > time-600 show nothing

Comment: it seems to work if its 10 minutes of actual time, what if i want the last 10 minutes relative to the end of the log

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to mention that bash script require Version 4.2 or higher.

Comment: You could retrieve log unixtime by `tail -n1 logfile | perl -MDate::Parse -nE 'say str2time($1) if /^(.{15})/'` or `date -r logfile +%s`.

Comment: @user1204671 I've modified my answer for adding *perl script* ready to use.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/303160/954777 for how to read the logfile from the end: can help to optimize a bit, especially if you have to parse uncommon date formats that are not supported by `Date::Parse`

Comment: great. a question. how can I put 600 inside a variable to run it in a bash script (I already did it and it doesn't work. e.g: perl -MDate::Parse -ne 'print if/^(.{15})\s/&&str2time($1)>time-$bantime'  and bantime=600)

Comment: I had already asked the question and it was answered at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897244/how-to-use-variable-in-perl-command-into-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can use the `date` command to parse the timestamps.  The ["%s" format specifier converts the given date to the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/date.1.html).  This simple integer is easy and accurate to do basic arithmetic on.

If you want the log messages from the last 10 minutes of actual time:

```
now10=$(($(date +%s) - (10 * 60)))

while read line; do
    [ $(date -d "${line:0:15}" +%s) -gt $now10 ] && printf "$line\n"
done < logfile
```

Note the `${line:0:15}` expression is a [bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) which gives the first 15 characters of the line, i.e. the timestamp itself.

If you want the log messages from the last 10 minutes relative to the end of the log:

```
$ lastline=$(tail -n1 logfile)
$ last10=$(($(date -d "$lastline" +%s) - (10 * 60)))
$ while read line; do
> [ $(date -d "${line:0:15}" +%s) -gt $last10 ] && printf "$line\n"
> done < logfile
Dec 18 10:19:16
Dec 18 10:19:23
Dec 18 10:21:03
Dec 18 10:22:54
Dec 18 10:27:32
$
```

Here's a mild performance enhancement over the above:

```
$ { while read line; do
> [ $(date -d "${line:0:15}" +%s) -gt $last10 ] && printf "$line\n" && break
> done ; cat ; }  < logfile
Dec 18 10:19:16
Dec 18 10:19:23
Dec 18 10:21:03
Dec 18 10:22:54
Dec 18 10:27:32
$
```

This assumes the log entries are in strict chronological order.  Once we match the timestamp in question, we exit the for loop, and then just use `cat` to dump the remaining entries.

Comment: I wonder why it return the following: ./test.sh: line 8: [: -gt: unary operator expected
date: invalid date `[pid 26481 on'
./test.sh: line 8: [: -gt: unary operator expected
date: invalid date `[pid 17563 on'
./test.sh: line 8: [: -gt: unary operator expected
Dec 18 10:19:16
Dec 18 10:19:23
Dec 18 10:21:03
Dec 18 10:22:54
Dec 18 10:27:32

Comment: -gt: unary operator expected  im on centos

Comment: @user1204671 - presumably your version of `date` can't parse the passed date string correctly.  What output do you get from `date --date="Dec 18 10:19:16"`?  What output do you get from `date --version`?  Which version of centos are you using?  I just installed 6.5 in a VM and it is working for me.

Comment: [root@s]# date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.4

[root@s]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

[root@s]# date --date="Dec 18 10:19:16"
Wed Dec 18 10:19:16 SGT 2013

Comment: seem to work now. there was a problem with the log file. Thanks buddy

Comment: ${line:0:15} +%s is awesome

Comment: there is a problem tho.. if the data is Dec 02 15:33:39
Dec 02 15:40:03
Dec 02 15:44:23 vv
Dec 02 15:44:57 vv

Comment: [root@s ~]# date -d "`tail -n1 /root/test.txt`" +%s
date: invalid date `Dec 02 15:44:57 vv'

Comment: i got it. just add line:0:15.

Comment: This is an example of bash parameter expansion.  `${line:0:15}` gives the first 15 characters of `$line`.  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: What if the log file has a 10000 -100000 lines? It will take  long to complete right?

Comment: Yes, if you have many lines, this is almost certainly not the most efficient way of doing this, as `date` gets invoked for every line.  The `python` solution is likely more performance-optimal, so long as it doesn't have to spawn external processes for each iteration.

Comment: Also see the latest edit which includes a mild performance enhancement http://stackoverflow.com/a/20649813/2113226

Comment: meaning it will still go through from the first line of the file until we match the timestamp in question? coz the log file is live and updated all the time in less than a second

Comment: Your solution implies 1 fork by lines, it's very expensive! Think about solutions using something like: `paste <(sed 's/^\(.\{15\}\).*$/\1/' logfile | date -f - +%s ) logfile` , use the commande `time myscript.sh` to evaluate the *cost* of your script...

Comment: Break the loop, instead of test and print each lines from first matching one! See my modified answer!

Comment: Yes - thats pretty good - I never noticed `date` can take a `-f` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you could do as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

astack=[]
with open("x.txt") as f:
    for aline in f:
        astack.append(aline.strip())
lasttime=datetime.strptime(astack[-1], '%b %d %I:%M:%S')
for i in astack:
    if (lasttime - datetime.strptime(i, '%b %d %I:%M:%S')).seconds <= 600:
        print i
```

Put the lines from the file into a stack (a python list). pop the last item and get difference between the successive date items until you get the difference as less than 600 seconds.

Running on your input, I get the following:

```
Dec 18 10:19:16
Dec 18 10:19:23
Dec 18 10:21:03
Dec 18 10:22:54
Dec 18 10:27:32
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    lasttime=datetime.strptime(astack[-1], '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  nhh

Comment: what id the log file contain Dec 18 10:19:16 sdsd
Dec 18 10:19:23 dsds
Dec 18 10:21:03 dssd
Dec 18 10:22:54 sdsds
Dec 18 10:27:32 sds

Comment: is there a way to take just the first 15 characters of the line?

Answer (score 0):

### **A Ruby solution (tested on ruby 1.9.3)**

You can pass days, hours, minutes or seconds as a parameter and it will search for the expression and on the file specified (or directory, in which case it will append '/*' to the name):

In your case just call the script like so: $0 -m 10 "expression" log_file

Note: Also if you know the location of 'ruby' change the shebang (first line of the script), 
for security reasons.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'date'
require 'pathname'

if ARGV.length != 4
        $stderr.print "usage: #{$0} -d|-h|-m|-s time expression log_file\n"
        exit 1
end
begin
        total_amount = Integer ARGV[1]
rescue ArgumentError
        $stderr.print "error: parameter 'time' must be an Integer\n"
        $stderr.print "usage: #{$0} -d|-h|-m|-s time expression log_file\n"
end

if ARGV[0] == "-m"
        gap = Rational(60, 86400)
        time_str = "%b %d %H:%M"
elsif ARGV[0] == "-s"
        gap = Rational(1, 86400)
        time_str = "%b %d %H:%M:%S"
elsif ARGV[0] == "-h"
        gap = Rational(3600, 86400)
        time_str = "%b %d %H"
elsif ARGV[0] == "-d"
        time_str = "%b %d"
        gap = 1
else
        $stderr.print "usage: #{$0} -d|-h|-m|-s time expression log_file\n"
        exit 1
end

pn = Pathname.new(ARGV[3])
if pn.exist?
        log = (pn.directory?) ? ARGV[3] + "/*" : ARGV[3]
else
        $stderr.print "error: file '" << ARGV[3] << "' does not exist\n"
        $stderr.print "usage: #{$0} -d|-h|-m|-s time expression log_file\n"
end

search_str = ARGV[2]
now = DateTime.now

total_amount.times do
        now -= gap
        system "cat " << log << " | grep '" << now.strftime(time_str) << ".*" << search_str << "'"
end
```