# How to get the last N minutes of log messages

Tags: bash, logging, awk

My logs are in this format:

```
[2018-01-22T13:40:22,825][WARN ] message
[2018-01-22T13:41:52,830][ERROR ] message
[2018-01-22T13:45:27,831][WARN ] message
```

I need to write a script that will check to see if there have been any errors in the last 5 minutes. From what I've found online, something like this should work:

```
awk -v d1="$(date --date="-5 min" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")" -v d2="$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' log.txt
```

But it doesn't. I think that the [ is getting in the way maybe? What else can I try?

Comment: Did u already saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649387/extract-last-10-minutes-from-logfile ?

Comment: @Black.Jack Yes, that's where I got my start on. But my format is different and I can't get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `[` is getting in the way.

The lexicographical compare, `$0 > d1`, compares something like:

```
[2018-01-22T13:45:27,831][WARN ] message
```

with

```
2018-01-22T13:45:27
```

and `[...` is always greater than any string starting with a number, e.g. `20..`.

Similarly for `$0 < d2` -- but in this case the **condition is *never* satisfied** (`[20..` is always greater than `20..`). That's why you're not getting any output.

A quick'n'dirty fix is to simply format `d1` and `d2` to start with `[`:

```
awk -v d1="$(date --date="-5 min" "+[%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")" -v d2="$(date "+[%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2' log
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks. I had tried adding the [ but I did it before the +...

Comment: @tannerwj you could also concatenation it in ask I think - just ‘$0 > “[“ d1’ for example in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

Sample `log.txt`:

```
[2018-01-22T13:40:22,825][WARN ] message
[2018-01-23T00:38:37,830][ERROR ] message
[2018-01-22T13:45:27,831][WARN ] message
```

---

```
awk -v d1="$(date --date="-5 min" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")" \
    -v d2="$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")" \
    '$2 > d1 && $2 < d2 && $4~/ERROR/' FS='[\\[\\]]' log.txt
```

- `FS='[\\[\\]]'` - treat square brackets as complex field separator

The output:

```
[2018-01-23T00:38:37,830][ERROR ] message
```

Comment: Wow, that's more than I thought possible with awk. I was just going to pipe that into grep and look for the errors I was watching for. I can modify this though and it'll help clean things up

Comment: `that's more than I thought possible with awk` - then you have a significant misunderstanding of what awk is :-)!