# how to use variable in perl command into a bash script

Tags: bash, perl

I have [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20665179/8747573) to review the last 10 min of the log:

```
perl -MDate::Parse -ne 'print if/^(.{15})\s/&&str2time($1)>time-600' /path/log
```

Now I want to put it in a script and put a variable instead of 600, to be able to modify the time more easily

```
#!/bin/bash
lasttime="600"
perl -MDate::Parse -ne 'print if/^(.{15})\s/&&str2time($1)>time-$lasttime' /path/log
# script does not end here. Run other commands like sed, grep etc. Why it should be in bash
```

But nothing comes out on the screen. But if I remove the variable it works fine

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -MDate::Parse -ne 'print if/^(.{15})\s/&&str2time($1)>time-600' /path/log
```

What should I modify so that it accepts the variable?

Comment: Why not just write a perl script then?

Comment: You are using single quotes they will not interpolate in Bash. But I would recommend using the `-s` option to pass a variable from Bash to perl, it is safer for injection attacks and you do not need to escape perl variables

Comment: because it is a bash that has other commands

Comment: Re "*You are using single quotes*", And keep it that way, Generating Perl code from a shell script is something you want to avoid!

Comment: @ikegami : It is usually to avoid, but in this case, the only tainted part is `lasttime`, and the OP sets this variable explicitly, so if he wants to shoot himself into the foot, he has to do it knowingly.

Comment: @ajcg Try this: `perl -MDate::Parse -sne 'print if/^(.{15})\s/&&str2time($1)>time-$lasttime'  -- -lasttime="$lasttime" -- /path/log`

Comment: @user1934428, Nothing to do with tainting; it's just too friggen complicated. ok, it might be integer here --I doubt its guaranteed, but let's assume it is-- so you could save a couple of characters, but it'll cost readability. So still bad.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Works!. Thanks. Please. Put the answer below to select it as correct

Comment: He can't as this question was closed as a duplicate of one with an answer that gives the above solution and two others.

Comment: Mmm. ok. So thanks again. It has been solved

Comment: in this other way it also works into a bash: `perl -MDate::Parse -ne "print if/^(.{15})\s/&&str2time(\$1)>time-$lasttime" /path/log`

Comment: @ajcg Did you read this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53524699/1765658 (and maybe upvote;) ?

Comment: @F.Hauri. Yes, and I have given my upvote. thanks