# What is the best way to get first 10 lines from a file without opening it (in perl)?

Tags: perl

If file size is very big, opening the file in perl will take some time. If I want only first/last 10 lines from the file, parsing the total file in memory and then get those lines should not be a optimal solution. 
I can use qx{head filename} for this purpose. Is any other way like any CPAN for this?

Comment: "Not opening" is not a sane requirement.  Not reading all of it into memory at once is probably what you want and need.

Comment: Also, "the best" without specifying criteria invites opinionated discussion. Tell us what you need and why, or settle for "a good enough way".

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303053/how-can-i-read-lines-from-the-end-of-file-in-perl -- the `head` case is trivial once you have that.

Answer (score 4):

You have to open the file, and read it line by line until the limit, like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 1;

open my $fh, '<', 'huge_filename' or die $!;
while( <$fh> ) {
    print; # Or push into array for further processing
    last if ++$count == 10;
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: Instead of the $count var, you could also use the built in $. , which already had the line number for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get any data from file without opening it. Also, time to open a file does not depend on file size - it should be instant.

If you need only first 10 lines, you have to open it, read 10 lines and close:

```
my @lines;

open my $fh, '<', $file_name;
for (1..10) {
    my $line = <$fh>;
    chomp $line; # optional, remove "\n" from end of line
    push @lines, $line;
}
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `<$fh>` return the next line of the file. So iterate with loop.

```
open my $fh,'<',"file" or die $!;
print scalar <$fh> for 1 .. 10;
```

You want to store the output in variable try as follow

```
my @ar;
open my $handler,'<',"split.py" or die $!;
push @ar, scalar <$handler> for 1 .. 2;
print @ar;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is any other way

It's easy enough to read just the first 10 lines into memory:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $OUTFILE, '>', 'data.txt';

for my $i (1..100_000) {
    say {$OUTFILE} "hello word $i";
}

close $OUTFILE;

open my $INFILE, '<', 'data.txt';

while (my $line = <$INFILE>) {
    print $line;
    last if $. >= 10;
}

close $INFILE;

--output:--
hello word 1
hello word 2
hello word 3
hello word 4
hello word 5
hello word 6
hello word 7
hello word 8
hello word 9
hello word 10
```

> like any CPAN for this?

For reading only the last 10 lines into memory:

```
use File::ReadBackwards;

open my $INFILE, '<', 'data.txt';
my $backwards_file = File::ReadBackwards->new('data.txt');

my $i = 1;
while (my $line = $backwards_file->readline) {
    print $line;
    last if ++$i > 10;
}

close $INFILE;

--output:--
hello word 100000
hello word 99999
hello word 99998
hello word 99997
hello word 99996
hello word 99995
hello word 99994
hello word 99993
hello word 99992
hello word 99991
```